# Error 404 on PHP Require calls, caused by case-sensitive difference

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I believe I've browsed a ton of different sites, blogs, and whatnots.

My PHP Website works great on my MAMP Stack in my computer (Working on a MAC, please don't judge).

The thing is, whenever I roll my website to my Production Server, running Ubuntu 18.04 (Regular LAMP Stack) I keep getting errors 404 when trying to use the site.

I've analyzed the paths, and the files do exist, however, in my code it's being required as

`/Tools/Php/initialScript.php`
and the actual path looks like 
```/Tools/PHP/initialScript.php````

I've already enabled mod_speling in my server, and restarted the whole thing a few times (more than I care to admit).

Does mod_speling even work for PHP require function?

Any guidance at this point would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting that you mention it works on Mac.  Mac paths as far as I know are case-insensitive.  Case in point, do `cd /to/SoMe/pAth` and it will work just fine.  On the other hand, Linux is case sensitive.

I would personally just not play loose with case and treat things as though they were case sensitive.  Is there something keeping that from being possible?

Comment: We're 3 different devs working on different modules, and eventually, we go and modify common directories. For some reason, even when we've try to standardize it, it always breaks up again. I think it's just paying more attention to it then. :S

Comment: Do you mean it breaks for at least one person even when everyone on the team uses case-sensitive naming?   That would be strange to me.

Comment: No, I mean there's someone who's not following naming conventions and need to work on that LOL.

Comment: I'm mostly used to code by myself, so this isn't an issue. Definitely a trick working with a team.